# Замена текстовых ссылок на гиперссылки в тексте

Tags: jquery, javascript, match, replace

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой.
есть текст с текстовыми ссылками, их надо заменить на гиперсылки.
Пример:

```
var mess = 'тут какой-то текст www.google.com www.google.com http://www.google.com тут текст*текст курсивом*'; 
var reg = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}):\/\/)*?([-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@{1})?(([-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,3})(:\d+)?((\/[-\+~%\/\.\w]+)?\/?([&?][-\+=&;%@\.\w]+)?(#[\w]+)?)?)/igm;

pregMatch = mess.match(reg);

mess = mess.replace(reg, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
```

*Но есть уловие если отсутствует протокол **http://** - добалять его.*

Я и циклом пробегался for и отслеживал наличие http:// врегулярке ивсе равботает, НО если две одинаковые ссылки в одном сообщении, тогда она сама себя начинает перезаписывать ...

Может кто-то глядя на условие, может подсказать вменяемое решение ...
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

**Примерно так:**

```
var mess = "тут какой-то текст www.google.com www.google.com http://www.google.com тут текст*текст курсивом* google.com https://google.com ftp://ftp.com";

var reg =  /(([a-z]+:\/\/(www\.)*)*[a-z0-9\-_]+\.[a-z]+)/igm;
pregMatch = mess.match(reg);
mess = mess.replace(reg, function(s){
  var str = (/:\/\//.exec(s) === null ? "http://" + s : s );
  return "<a href=\""+ str + "\">" + str /*s*/ + "</a>"; 
});
```

Comment: м?

    /(\w+:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.\w+/g

Comment: ну да можно и так так лучше!!!
немного изменил: /(\w+:\/\/)?(www\.)?[\w+\-]+\.\w+/g;

Comment: @Виталик осталось еще правильно обрабатывать уже имеющиеся ссылки внутри исходного сообщения)) Хотя автор про них ничего не указал.

Comment: @lampa, например?

Comment: @Виталик 

    var mess = "тут какой-то текст <a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a> http://www.google.com тут текст*текст курсивом* google.com https://google.com ftp://ftp.com";

Я думаю в replace функции стоит проверять, стоит ли первым http? (/^https?/i)